# How to intercept reading of plist values in Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, urbanairship.com

We're using the new [Urban Airship iOS plugin](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push) for PhoneGap.

In the plugin's plist file, we're supposed to enter the app-specific keys needed to enable push notifications.

The problem is we have two versions, free and paid, of the same app, but the plist file only accommodates one version.

Essentially, we need to modify the Objective-C code to read different plist values, depending on whether it's the free or premium version.

We currently manage both versions with the same code base and Xcode project. Unless we change the plugin code, it seems like we need to create a new Xcode project, which we don't want to do.

How do we adjust Urban Airship's Objective-C files to read different values from the plsit file?

Comment: Using multiple targets and custom build preprocessors for each one you could easily have a `PRO` preprocessor that would allow you to have a simple if statement where necessary. You can even have separate files for each target. I use this often for plists specifically.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. How could I configure the Xcode project to read a different plist file? Also could you please add this as an answer?

Comment: @RyanPoolos, in case the notification didn't go through since you weren't tagged, this is another comment so you know i responded. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to keep you waiting, I wanted to give you a very detailed answer instead of rushing last night :) So here we go.

First in your project we need to add a new target. Go to your project settings and right click your target. Click duplicate.

[image: Duplicate your target.]

You'll get a new target probably named Target-copy. You'll also get a new info.plist file just for that target.

[image: Xcode will automatically create a new info.plist.]

Next we're going to edit our Pro version's Built Settings. Scroll or search and find *Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 Preprocessing*. Add to both your Debug and Release configurations. I normally just go with the simple `PRO=1`. You also need to add `PRO=0` to your lite version or it will be undefined when you try to build that version.

[image: Create a custom PRO preprocessor.]

Now lets look at how to add a custom plist like I'm sure you'll need. First create two folders. Its important these are folders not groups. In each folder we can create a plist with the exact same filename.

[image: Add one to the Lite target.]
[image: Add one to the Pro target]

Since Now you can add something to each of them. I just added a key `property` and a value `pro string` / `lite string`. Finally to the code. In the sample project I made I simple overrode `viewDidLoad` but obviously this will work anywhere. Since the plists have the same name you can load them with one line of code. They'll never get mixed up because they are only copied to their respective target. If you need to do code level based logic you can use the `PRO` preprocessor we made.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This will load the proper plist automatically.
    NSLog(@"Plist Value: %@",[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"]] objectForKey:@"property"]);

    // Also remember we set up a preprocessor PRO. you can use it as well.
    if (PRO) {
        NSLog(@"Only Show for Pro");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Only Show for Lite");
    }

    NSLog(@"This will show for both");
}
```

This is the method I use for all my lite/pro version apps so I can share a common codebase without copying it between projects or other complicated systems. It has worked pretty well for me so far :) Happy Coding!

**Source**

Figured someone may be able to use the project to look at so here it is on [GitHub](https://github.com/EmperiorEric/LitePro).

Comment: Thanks, Ryan! Wow. This was very detailed, but I think the last screen shot is what we needed since our goal is simply to add a plist file to an existing plugin. The problem is, we can't seem to find where the plist file is loaded in the plugin: https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push/tree/master/ios-sample/UAPhonegapSample/Plugins/PushNotificationPlugin

Comment: Is the syntax sometimes different from what you used?

Comment: You should probably follow the first part of my post where you have a separate target and add the same named plist to different targets. Then you wouldn't need to see where its loaded it would just automatically load the right one.

Comment: Then you'll be able to have one `AirshipConfig.plist` for each target each with custom values.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan! We already had separate targets before adding the plugin. Does this mean we need to add the plugin to each target?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the plugin for each target. just the unique plist. If its not unique you don't need it for each. I'm assuming the plugin is is exactly the same and should be shared.

Comment: Ahhh, just add the plist to each target using the steps outlined above? The plugin should be shared between targets ... the only difference would be the plist values.

Comment: Yep. I believe that should work :) Then you won't have to worry about messing with code at all. Xcode and the plugin will just "find" the right plist for each target.

Comment: Hmm, there only seems to be one plist file for both targets. Is this because we created the separate targets before adding the plugin? Should we delete the premium target, then recreate it? Or how can we attach a second plist file to the premium target?

Comment: You need a folder for premium and a folder for lite. Then put the same plist in each one. Then make sure each on including folder is attached to the proper target. You will probably need to clean before you build as well. You don't need to delete the plugin but you may need to delete the original plist and add it back twice to make it easier to add to the targets.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. How do you create new folders? We don't see the option within Xcode -- only projects and files.

Comment: The easiest way is to create a folder in Finder then drag it into Xcode. Make sure the "Create Groups for any added Folders" is checked. You can also associate already created groups with Folders by going into the groups info inspector and changing its relative path.